# Simple Question about javascript remoting

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting

i have a JavaScript array and i want to send it as an argument to a remote method using javascript remoting , here is the javascript array:

```
  var quizQuestions  = [
    {
            type: "multiple",
            text: "Quelles sont les sanctions pour lesquels un entretien préalable est obligatoire ?",
            possibilities: [
            {
                correctAnswer:0,
                questionMultiple:"Rupture anticipée pour faute grave",
                possibilities: [
                {
                    answer: "Oui"
                },
                {
                    answer: "Non"
                }
                ],
            selected: null,
            correct: null
            },
            {
                correctAnswer:1,
                questionMultiple:"Avertissement",
                possibilities: [
                {
                    answer: "Oui"
                },
                {
                    answer: "Non"
                }
                ],
            selected: null,
            correct: null
            },
                {
                correctAnswer:0,
                questionMultiple:"Mise à pied disciplinaire",
                possibilities: [
                {
                    answer: "Oui"
                },
                {
                    answer: "Non"
                }
                ],
            selected: null,
            correct: null
            }
            ],
            selected: null,
        },


        {
            type: "multiple",
            text: "Pour chaque type de visite médicale, préciser les délais de passage des visites :",
            possibilities: [
            {
                correctAnswer:0,
                questionMultiple:"Embauche",
                possibilities: [
                {
                    answer: "avant la fin de la période d'essai"
                },
                {
                    answer: "dans les 8 premiers jours"
                },
                {
                    answer: "avant la prise de poste"
                }
                ],
            selected: null,
            correct: null
            },
            {
                correctAnswer:1,
                questionMultiple:"Après une absence d’au moins 30 jours pour cause d’accident du travail,de maladie",
                possibilities: [
                {
                    answer: "avant la fin de la période d'essai"
                },
                {
                    answer: "dans les 8 premiers jours"
                },
                {
                    answer: "avant la prise de poste"
                }
                ],
            selected: null,
            correct: null
            },
                {
                correctAnswer:2,
                questionMultiple:"Surveillance médicale des travailleurs handicapés",
                possibilities: [
                {
                    answer: "avant la fin de la période d'essai"
                },
                {
                    answer: "dans les 8 premiers jours"
                },
                {
                    answer: "avant la prise de poste"
                }
                ],
            selected: null,
            correct: null
            }
            ],
            selected: null,
        }
]
```

is it possible to send it as an argument ? and if yes how to handle it in the remoting method in the controller ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider parse it as a JSON string and send it as a string parameter to server. And at the server side, you can deserialize it via Apex. You need to define a custom wrapper class to hold the value.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm

Comment: can you explain more please i am new to salesforce and did not catch all what you have said

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim Are you new to programming as well?

Comment: No really i am doing oriented object programming for while . did you mean that i an pass it directly like that
  ' Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            'ApexRemoteActionPageController.myContacts', quizQuestions,
            function(result, event){ } ' as an argument

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim It would be easy then. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify . You need to stringify the object as a string and pass that string as a parameter. And in your apex class. You can deserialize that string into an array of custom objects